# WinHlp32.exe on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

Is there a *official* way to install a `WinHlp32.exe` on a Windows Server 2012? I've [tried installing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917607) a versions for Windows 8 and for Windows Server 2008 R2 but both installers failed (incompatible product in first case, and some signature problem in the latter case).

Comment: You should know that the .hlp file format was discontinued years ago. This is clearly indicated in the article you linked too. **"The Windows Help program is not supported for Windows 8 Server Beta, and no download will be provided for this Windows version.""** Windows 8 Server Beta clearly became known as Window Server 2012.

Comment: @Ramhound oh, I've missed that in a rush, that answers it. Still that is strange it's available for Win8 but not Win8 Srv. I do know that this format is obsolete, however it's hard to argue about it for a software released in 2002, which happens to have documentation in that format.

Comment: Your only options might be to use the app in a VM with a version of Windows that supports WinHelp, or use one of the available (mostly commercial) .HLP decompilers/format converters.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin - Windows 8 was released in a 32-bit option Windows Server 2012 was not.  All the other supported operating systems were also.

Comment: @Karan I've just copied it from other system at hand, I was just wondering if there is more elegant way to do this. Obviously there isn't.

Comment: isn't it silly that Microsoft has software like "Active Directory Users and Computers" in Windows Server 2012 R2 that have the classic "?" button on their dialogs then? Clicking on it opens a popup saying help can't be displayed because a component is missing from Windows and pointing you to the WinHlp32 download page / kb article, that in turn says it isn't available for Windows Server 2012 R2. Totally broken user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official way to install WinHlp32 on Windows Server 2012. The only way around is to "borrow" it from an other system (or the internet if you can take some risk).